# Inspecting what caused session_start() and why?

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, global-asax

I am working on a spaghetti code !!!!! 
It has it's own logic for Login and authenticating users and this code not using standard routine of .Net Framework to authentication of users(Membership Providers and ...), It stores data inside session variable and use them when needed. 
But in this process we have many response.redirect() and server.transfer() 
and after some points many times Session_Start() of Global.asax is called and these calls clear session variables as you may already know. 
I reviewed call stack of Session_start() call over and over again but because session_start() is starting point of a request I can not understand why this method was called and what reason caused this call , please someone tell me "What is main reason of calling Session_start() ? Is it only redirection to a new page of web application or there other reasons too ? How can I inspect the real trace of calling Session_Start() ?"

Answer (score 0):

This is called internally by the ASP.NET platform when you request for a resource (e.g, ASPX page) for the first time in the *current* session (when the session-id is created for the first time).

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx):

> The Session_OnStart subroutine is run at the beginning of a request if the
>   request begins a new session. A new session will be started if a
>   request is made that does not contain a SessionID value or if the
>   SessionID property contained in the request references a session that
>   has expired. You can use the Session_OnStart event to initialize
>   session variables as well as to track session-related information.

Comment: I checked this, and unfortunately Session variables are null on that method too .

Comment: @MahyarPasarzangene of course, because this is the **start** of the session. Don't except for any variables inside - only later!

Comment: well , I mentioned that we fill session variable before session_start calls but unexpectedly session_start called and all variable will be lost !